# Js RegExp split every other line

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm new at using regex and can't figure out how to do this.

I have grouped data which are separated every other line, like so:

```
Liste #1
val 1; val2; val3
Liste #2
...
```

and the output should be :

```
Array(
    "Liste #1
val 1; val2; val3", 
    "Liste #2
val 1; val2; val3"
)
```

How do I acheive this?

I will then split the result again, forming a structure like :
`Array(0 => ['title' =>, 'values' => Array()])`
but I assumed this would require 3 splits.

Comment: What do you want to spit into what? Your question is unclear.

Comment: @bjb568 I need to split every 2 lines so I and can then split again into smaller parts... The later seems easy enough but I'm not sure exacly how to split every other line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why use regex, just read two lines at a time?

```
var lines = data.split('\n');
for (var i = 0; i < lines.length ; i = i + 2) {
    var myarray = [];
    myarray.push(lines[i]); //this doesn't strip '\n'
    myarray.push(lines[i+1]); //this doesn't strip '\n'
}
```

Comment: I'm using regex to split line breaks elsewhere in the code, so I figured it might be reusable here, but this solution also works. Thanks.